# php xpath screen scrape issue

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping

Ok, this seems so simple but I can't get this coding working at all...

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.groupon.com/deals/the-newfoundland-shop');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "/html/body/div[@id='global_container']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='content']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[@id='number_sold_container']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
$buys = "$n->nodeValue";
```

Please help before I loose it...

Thanks

Comment: *(tipp)* http://www.groupon.com/pages/api

Comment: @Gordon Where's your sense of adventure? ;-)

Comment: @middaparka I am not *that* adventurous after having read http://www.groupon.com/terms chapter 5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax for XPath -

/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/xhtml:div[@id='global_container'] ...

If dont helped check if your XPath is ok ( it is really long )

Answer (score 0):

First FAQ: the page looks proper XHTML, so you need to register the XHTML namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` with some prefix, and use that prefix in your XPath expression.

Second FAQ: you should note that original source has not `tbody` element. This is added by the browser.